# Why do validations not work correctly when testing my asp.net mvc 2 application via 3rd party tool(s)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, error-handling, fiddler

I am working with an ASP.NET MVC 2 application that performs basic CRUD operations against a DB2 table. When testing my application by simply loading it in I.E., if I put characters in a numbers field or numbers in a date field or some other form of data that is incompatible with the datatype in my View Model, MVC performs correct error processing on its end and the view is returned with the appropriate Model State Error messages as displayed by the Html.ValidationSummary() mvc helper.

However, when I run tests with programs such as IBM AppScan or forge POST requests with Fiddler2, the application flips out.

I am performing what I believe to be the same sort of test in 2 different ways and am getting various results.

I am also employing the use of MVC'S AntiForgeryToken system, but that doesn't do much good because these programs just scan the request data, find the token, and make sure it's included with their forged POST.

Also note that I am using DataAnnotations on the server side to handle several of these validations and instead of getting the error the annotations ought to return, the page is redirected to the applications error page for uncaught exceptions.

I'm actually quite baffled by all this. What am I missing?

Comment: Probably because you are not doing it right. What is the difference in posted data between POST created in browser and in Fiddler? Can't you monitor request in Fiddler to see the difference?

Comment: Okay, correction. Forged data done via a post through Fiddler is correctly validated; this leaves the mystery of whatever IBM AppScan is doing.

Comment: Can't you check `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form` on server side?

Comment: See updated question. You pointed me in the right direction. It was an ID10T error on my part.

Comment: Please remember to post your answer as answer and mark it as correct. Don't place solution in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LukLed's comment had me do a sanity check on things and he's absolutely right. I'm doing it wrong. When I forged request body details in Fiddler, I did it in a way where I knew the data would be incorrect, but the data would also fall under the correct validations, so the error would be caught. My testing such as submitting characters for a number only field (I had thought this is the sort of thing that bombed the app when AppScan tested it) gave the correct results.

However, LukLed's comment had me really look at the POST data AppScan sent. In every application error, the field was a string on the viewmodel. I allowed the data to pass without strenuous checks on length and a "String data right truncation." SQL ERROR ensued. This also brought to light that I need to do better sanitizing of the data because some of the values AppScan submitted were like:

'../../../../../../../../../../../../bin/id|' for an account number field
and

Foobar%0d%0aAppScanHeader:%20AppScanValue%2f1%2e2%2d3%0d%0aSecondAppScanHeader:%20whatever' for a description field.

Special characters such as these ought not be allowed in the form submission.